# How to press and hold a key?

Tags: vb.net, input, keyboard, wait

I'm creating a program to automatically interface with another application using my mouse and keyboard. I've found code which will click the key once and release it immediately (as far as i know); this is SendKeys.Send("{up}"). Please dont over complicate things if you can, im learning on the go here.

My question is how do I send a keypress and hold it for a length of time determined by a variable. I roughly want to:

```
Press and hold arrow key "up"
wait(Random.next(1,10))
Release arrow key "up"
```

I'm writing it in Visual basic within Visual studio 17 community.

Thanks!

After looking at Valyrean Groups code i have edited it down to this:

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Private Declare Function MapVirtualKey Lib "user32" Alias "MapVirtualKeyA" (ByVal wCode As Integer, ByVal wMapType As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub HoldKeyDown(ByVal key As Byte, ByVal durationInSeconds As Integer)

    keybd_event(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), 0, 0) ' Down
    Threading.Thread.Sleep((RandNum.Next(1000, 5000)))
    keybd_event(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), 2, 0) ' Up

End Sub
```

My question is now how do i change the arrow key being pressed and held?

Comment: FYI `keybd_event()` is deprecated and replaced by [**`SendInput()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to use the `keybd` event library from System32.  Add the following code to your form.

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Private Declare Function MapVirtualKey Lib "user32" Alias "MapVirtualKeyA" (ByVal wCode As Integer, ByVal wMapType As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub HoldKeyDown(ByVal key As Byte, ByVal durationInSeconds As Integer)
    Dim targetTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now().AddSeconds(durationInSeconds)
    keybd_event(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), 0, 0) ' Down
    While targetTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now()).TotalSeconds > 0
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    keybd_event(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), 2, 0) ' Up
End Sub
```

**Then to use it...**

```
HoldKeyDown(Keys.Up,3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, although this might work Im looking for something as simple as can be. Im using a timer to help with the hold length; could this make it easier? And I want to repeat this for all directions of arrow (up,down,left,right) so it might become a fairly large peice to do the job

Comment: The code would not get any larger.  And this is fairly simple...  to "hold" another key, just call the function again with the other key and amount of time.

Comment: Just call the function with whatever key you want to be held.  `HoldKeyDown(Keys.Down,5)` or `HoldKeyDown(Keys.Left,4)`. Will hold arrow down for 5 seconds, the other will hold Left for 4 seconds.

Comment: **Don't call `Application.DoEvents()` in a no-delay loop!** It will eat alot of CPU, and frankly, you shouldn't be calling `DoEvents()` at all! Use Async/Await, threads, or timers instead.

Comment: See: [**Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

Comment: Also keep in mind that `keybd_event()` is infact deprecated and replaced by [**`SendInput()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx).